# What is the difference between topological phase and topological defect

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order

I'm familiar with some examples of topological defects: domain wall, cosmic string, vortex, and also know some examples of topological phases of matter:  [Kitaev's Majorana model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0010440v2.pdf),  [Kitaev's honeycomb model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0506438v3.pdf), and have heard about quantum Hall liquids.

> It seems that they all have some nontrivial topological structures. But what are their relations and difference?

According to Wikipedia, *Topological defects are not only stable against small perturbations, but cannot decay or be undone or be de-tangled, precisely because there is no continuous transformation that will map them (homotopically) to a uniform or "trivial" solution.*

Given this robustness, could topological defects also be used in fault-tolerant quantum computation, similar to topological quantum computation?

Comment: Which of the two questions you ask is your question?  (I also feel the first one is too broad: Basically, you say "I have two things with the word 'topological' in it, what is their relation/difference."  Then you could also start asking about topological spaces.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch My first question mean, for example, are there any cases where a topological defect is also a topological phase? And, given a quantum system that have some nontrivial topological properties, how could we judge whether it is a topological defect or a topological phase?

Comment: What does it *mean* that a "topological defect is also a topological phase"?

Comment: One thing which has indeed been studied how topological defects on e.g. lattices affect a topological model defined on this lattice.